# If statement pertaining to database criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, if-statement

I am brand new to this community. I am also somewhat new to programming and this is a noob question. If my wording is bad or any members have any advice to give a newbie please do! Anyway, here I go!

The following method (although its obvious), grabs a file and inserts it into a database table (KC_Reply_Shipped), (or cancels into another table), also obvious. The file looks something like this

YYYY847583  blahblahblah  blah   blahahasdf blah blah

XXX8343445  "               "           "        "

XXX8976556  "               "         "           "

However, I do NOT want to insert the YYYY. I can not help that the File has this, because it is out of my control. But I DO want the XXX. Sometimes the file will have YYYY and sometimes it will not.

although this seems so easy, me being noob, I get confused on the wording because I already have a while statement and the method is boolean. FYI this is only for fun and experimentation. Nothing serious. Any help or answer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you^2 in advance!

```
    private bool InsertIntoDatabase(FileInfo file)
    {
        string table = "KC_Reply_Shipped";
        string line;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName);
        try
        {
            Database db = new Database();
            ShippedOrders = new List<string[]>();
            CancelledOrders = new List<string[]>();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] temp = GetFileDataForInsert(line);
                temp[temp.Length - 1] = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4);
                if (temp[1] == "30")
                {
                    table = "KC_Reply_Cancelled";
                    CancelledOrders.Add(temp);
                    db.UpdateOrderToCancelled(temp[0]);
                }
                else
                {
                    ShippedOrders.Add(temp);
                    db.UpdateOrderToShipped(temp[0]);
                    db.UpdateOrderTrackingNumber(temp[10]);
                    db.UpdateOrderNotes(temp);
                }
                db.BatchInsert(table, temp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMsg = e.Message;
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: are you wanting to remove the 'YYYY' or to ignore files that begin with 'YYYY'?

Comment: Ignore the file. At any given time, if there is a YYYY, there will only be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following to check the start of the line and the make a decision from there:

```
if(!line.StartsWith("YYYY"))
{
     //....do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is case sensitive.

Comment: If case sensitivity was an issue then line.ToUpper().StartsWith("YYYY") should cover it.

Comment: I dont think it is an issue. They will always be upper case. Thanks Andy!

Comment: This code looks great, but I have a question, If I remove the YYYY and the database proceeds to process the rest of the data, would there be an error since all the other entities are XXX(7 ints), can the database store just 6 ints?

Comment: I would think if the database can store XXX1234567 it would be able to store 123456. I have modified my answer to reflect the fact that you have confirmed you wish to ignore files starting with YYYY.

Comment: Thank you Andy, you have helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the lines starting with YYYY like this:

```
...

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("YYYY"))
        continue;
    else {
        // your code
    }
}

...
```

If you want to ignore the file in case there is a "YYYY" then you can do this:

```
...

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("YYYY"))
        return true; // or false, whatever you method should return in this case
    else {
        // your code
    }
}

...
```